# Como emitir um som ao passar o mouse em ANGULAR?

Tags: angular

Gostaria que emitisse um som ao passar o mouse nos menus da minha aplicação, mas não sei como fazer

HTML:

```
<div class="itemsMenu" ng-mouseover="playAudio()"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></div>
```

main.component.ts:

```
playAudio(){
    let audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "/assets/menu.wav";
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente trocar a tag div, para audio. Irá funcionar nos seguintes navegadores

Firefox 3.5+, 
Chrome 3+, 
Opera 10.5+, 
Safari 4+, 
IE 9+

```
<audio>
    <source src="audio/beep.mp3"></source>
    <source src="audio/beep.ogg"></source>
</audio>
```